# boto3 api not returning new files in list if uploaded to s3 via GUI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a set of boto3 powered commands in python.  they seem to be working great to download files from S3.

```
bucket = s3_client.Bucket(bucket_name)
for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=key_dir):
    # Iterate over all files to download
```

The trouble is, I've now tested uploading a file manually via the GUI to this same bucket and prefix area.. I can see the file is listing, it is of a non-zero size... all uploaded well from the GUI.. BUT

When I repeat the API calls like above... all the same older files come back just fine.. but my brand new file is omitted from the list..

Do I need to bust a cache or something?  Seems the AWS Boto3 library by default is only seeing long lived files..

Comment: What do you mean by "When I repeat the API calls like above"? Do you mean that you killed the previous process and ran the same script again?

Comment: AWS S3 is [strongly consistency](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/consistency/), meaning you should see the files immediately once they're in the bucket.  If you're not, something details not mentioned in this question must be impacting your listing.

Comment: @jellycsc, I mean I want to list and download the same bucket + prefix... to prove that the new files are being properly uploaded.. but when I run the script .. i just get back the older files and nothing that I've uploaded manually

Comment: @AnonCoward I can see the files in the GUI.. but not in my API calls via the code shown.. if there's something more you want me to show just lmk.. I am as confused as ever since.. yeah I expect once i see the files in the GUI.. it should be returning via API call too...

Comment: Recommend you re-test on a new, temporary bucket with just a couple of objects in it.

Comment: @jarmod , I went ahead and created a brand new bucket.. uploaded a file via my code to it.  That worked fine and I see the file in the GUI.. then I uploaded another file manually via GUI.. and NOW... it seems my code is seeing the new file right away...

I can only conclude that... my other bucket is too old or I need to modify permissions of that bucket somehow?

Comment: Or you're listing the wrong bucket/prefix. I know that sounds unlikely, but it fits the symptoms. Any chance that is what's happening? If the bucket/prefix is definitely correct, then can you share which region this bucket is in and confirm whether or not the listing is corrected if you re-run it later (e.g. 10 minutes after the upload).

Comment: im in US-WEST-1 .. My code seems to work with new buckets .. but not my bucket that was created back in 2018.. leading me to think I need to probably just download and cleanup that bucket with a new fresh bucket..  I checked the keys and files were downloading fine .. except in the older bucket I do not get some text files.. strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior seems isolated to a bucket made in 2018.. so I plan to just ignore this and create a new bucket.. once I had a new bucket this behavior stopped altogether.. strange,  but hope it helps others who might see this